# starting with gs-producing-web-service

Tags: spring, web-services, gradle, build.gradle

I'm newbe in Java and Spring.
I tried to start with https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/
I downloaded the content for inital and complet solution into STS 3.9.5 IDE with gradle bulidship 2.0. But setup this project is not ready to use.
In package *hello* imports seem be bad.

*import io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.GetCountryRequest;
import io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service.GetCountryResponse;*

I get message ***"The import io cannot be resolved"***

How can I fix it?

I didn't change anything in bulid.gradle:

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// tag::xsd[]
task genJaxb {
    ext.sourcesDir = "${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb"
    ext.classesDir = "${buildDir}/classes/jaxb"
    ext.schema = "src/main/resources/countries.xsd"

    outputs.dir classesDir

    doLast() {
        project.ant {
            taskdef name: "xjc", classname: "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
            mkdir(dir: sourcesDir)
            mkdir(dir: classesDir)

            xjc(destdir: sourcesDir, schema: schema) {
                arg(value: "-wsdl")
                produces(dir: sourcesDir, includes: "**/*.java")
            }

            javac(destdir: classesDir, source: 1.6, target: 1.6, debug: true,
                    debugLevel: "lines,vars,source",
                    classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath) {
                src(path: sourcesDir)
                include(name: "**/*.java")
                include(name: "*.java")
            }

            copy(todir: classesDir) {
                fileset(dir: sourcesDir, erroronmissingdir: false) {
                    exclude(name: "**/*.java")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// end::xsd[]

task afterEclipseImport {
    dependsOn "genJaxb"
}

// tag::jaxb[]
configurations {
    jaxb
}

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-producing-web-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    from genJaxb.classesDir
}

// tag::dependencies[]
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("wsdl4j:wsdl4j:1.6.1")
    jaxb("org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11")
    compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
}
// end::dependencies[]
// end::jaxb[]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't find any folder named "jaxb". In Project Explorer there is not folder genereted-sources. How can I run task genJaxb ? - the project is synchronized without any error message.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error when I imported the project from here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service

On intelliJ right click on the project and scroll down to the maven option.

Click **"Generate Sources and Update Folders"** and that will generate the domain classes for the project.

Comment: it did nothing in my case.

Answer (score 2):

These classes from `io.spring.guides.gs_producing_web_service` package are generated by the `genJaxb` task: the generated source files are located in `${buildDir}/generated-sources/jaxb`, and the compiled classes in `${buildDir}/classes/jaxb`.

In order to generate these sources & classes, simply execute Gradle task `build`, this will trigger execution of `genJaxb`

After a first build, you will need to perform a "Refresh Gradle Project", to make the generated classes "visible" by Eclipse, then the import error should be fixed.

Comment: "Refresh Gradle Project" dosen't work - the message is succes, but errors still are red.

Comment: you have "Build Automatically" checked? @M.Ricciuti

Answer (score 0):

I chose from context menu "Spring Tools/Update Maven Dependencies" and next "Configure/Add gradle nature" and problems are gone.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check that pom hasn't red underlines inside and then right click on pom.xm -> maven -> Generate Sources and Update Folders.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).